# В eclipse проект работает, после сборки проекта maven не работает

Tags: eclipse, maven, jlayer

В проекте (mp3 плеер) использую `jlayer`
В `pom.xml` зависимости добавил, в лок.репозитории jar лежит. Но после создания maven-ом `jar` - окошко рисуется, но `.mp3` файлы  по нажатию кнопки не проигрываются. Совершенно непонятно - где может быть баг?

Мой **pom.xml**

```
    <!-- стандартная часть -->
    <!-- установка кодировки -->
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.4</version>
              <configuration>
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>sss.ppp</mainClass>   <!--указывает какой класс главный-->
                  </manifest>
                </archive>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javazoom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlayer</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш dependency "javazoom" не добавляется в .jar файл

P.S. вместо вашего класса "sss.ppp", я использую "com.example.MyMainClass".
Нужно создать файл src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Заполнить его данными:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MyMainClass
```

В pom.xml добавить плагины:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>
                        src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
                    </manifestFile>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.example.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>
                        src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
                    </manifestFile>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.example.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

После этого выполнить фазу "clean" и затем заново собрать проект, выполнить фазу "package". Запустить файл MyMainClass-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies

Comment: Спасибо, большое, всё заработало. Правда не сразу, я еще умудрился ошибку в манифесте допустить - пробел не оставил между двоеточием и именем класса, но разобрался:o) Спасибо за помощь.